# initialising a global mixin in weex

Tags: vue.js, weex

I initialised a weex and vue app using `weex create awesome-project`. In the `entry.js` file I am trying to register a global mixin but it does not seem to be registering. The code is is:

```
import weex from 'weex-vue-render'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    device () {
      return 'mobile'
    },
    browser () {
      return this.device === 'browser'
    },
    mobile () {
      return this.device === 'mobile'
    }
  }
})

weex.init(Vue)
```

None of the component have `this.mobile` as true. Works fine in the web simulator but not when I scan the QR code on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI figured this out. Seems I just had a broken version of Weex! If you find yourself suffering from this problem, simply update Weex, init a new project and move all your code over. Worked like a charm for me.